# Highchart Export to PDF Does Not Fit to a Single A4 Landscape Page

Tags: javascript, highcharts, phantomjs, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin Charts 4.0.5 right now and it is derived from Highcharts. According to the Highchart developers and its documentation, the SourceWidth and SourceHeight format has to be specified (in Number parameter value) in order to export a chart to PDF in a A4 landscape format. Scaling is set to 1.

This is written in these lines of code (as a start, I used 800x600):

```
Exporting export = new Exporting(true);
export.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/highcharts-export-web")
export.setSourceWidth(800);
export.setSourceHeight(600);
export.setScale(1);
```

After playing around with the sizing, I was somehow unsatisfied with the results as:

- The chart didn't reach the end (after setting to 3508 in width, A4 equivalent)
- The x-axis tick intervals didn't reflect the intervals on the web browser (e.g I set the intervals for 500 in Vaadin code, but the tick intervals in PDF is 100)
- The chart also wasn't able to fit in a page.

Note: For simplicity, I am using a basic line and bar chart.

I have a vanilla version of the Highchart export server installed in my local and in our staging environment, with my local having the legacy Tomcat/Java version of the export server.

Where should I change the settings for that?

**UPDATES:**

Trying to simulate with the sample- it behaves differently in JSFiddle vs in the local highchart server.

1. Sample in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mykp0648/1/).
2. Sample attached output in PDF that got doesn't fit into the page[image: PDF Output doesn't fit in one page]:
3. Vanilla version of highchart-convert.js (github version [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/blob/master/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js))

**UPDATE 2:**

4. Output in PDF using the public export.highcharts.com server (the export.setURL line in the code has been commented out):
   [image]

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in the online code editor (jsfiddle)? I mean only highcharts exporting - check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/y1qgjd0s/1/.

Comment: @WojciechChmiel - apologies for the lateness. I was spending a few more days to try out other approaches. I've updated the post above.

Comment: Have you tried to add an additional `exporting.chartOptions` to prevent truncating? Increase `chart.margin`, see http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/w5ncpt1z/.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, chart.margin only affects in the web page content. The Java API derived from Highcharts API doesn't have that. I also tested but using the external export.highcharts.com server (instead of my local highchart export server) and the scaling adjustment seems to be happening in the PDF file. I'll update the post above with these info.